# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update a data using a specific ID which is not working but gives above error.

When I update, first I search the database for that specific id and then save the data to `MongoDB`

here is my `server.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//importing MongoDB model schema
let ToDo = require('./todo.model');

const app = express();
const todoRoutes = express.Router();

const PORT = 4000;

//middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/todos', todoRoutes);

//connection to the MongoDB database
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/todos', {useNewUrlParser: true});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () =>{
    console.log("Connected to the MongoDB through port: 27017");
 });

app.listen(PORT, () => { 
    console.log(`Listening to port: ${PORT}`);
});

//get all data - removed to show only the code snippet I am getting errors

//get data by an ID - removed to show only the code snippet I am getting errors

//add items to database -removed to show only the code snippet I am getting errors

//update items
todoRoutes.route('/update/:id').post((req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    ToDo.findById(id, (err, todo) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!todo) res.status(400).send("No data found");

        todo.todo_description = req.body.todo_description;
        todo.todo_responsible = req.body.todo_responsible;
        todo.todo_priority = req.body.todo_priority;
        todo.todo_completed = req.body.todo_completed;
        res.end();

        todo.save().then(todo => {
            res.json(200).send("Data Updated! " + todo);
            res.end();
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Error occured! " + err);
        });
    });
});
```

This is the error I am getting...

[image: Error]

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually means that you send a response more than once.

Notice that you send two responses one after the other `res.json()` and `res.end()`

If you want for some reason to just end the response, use `res.end()`, otherwise use `res.status(200).json({ result: ‘Data updated’ + todo })`

If you send both, it will complain about trying to modify the response (via `res.end()`) after sending it (via `res.status().json()`)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

In the `'/update/:id'` route, you're sending a `res.end()` then doing it again 3 lines later.  If you remove the first `res.end()`, it should work.

You should also `return` if `todo` is missing:

```
todoRoutes.route('/update/:id').post((req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    ToDo.findById(id, (err, todo) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!todo) return res.status(400).send("No data found");

        todo.todo_description = req.body.todo_description;
        todo.todo_responsible = req.body.todo_responsible;
        todo.todo_priority = req.body.todo_priority;
        todo.todo_completed = req.body.todo_completed;

        todo.save().then(todo => {
            res.status(200).send("Data Updated! " + todo);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("Error occured! " + err);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am still getting the error even after commenting that.

Comment: I added a "return" to the `if(!todo)` statement.  That may be where the first set of headers are being sent.

Comment: Can you try if else blog

Comment: You are sure you restarted the server before running his changes? I also noted that immediately. @user11436513

Comment: @ZacharyBrooks, yes. I did several times.I am using `postman` google chrome extension. Do I need to restart that too?

Comment: I made an additional change.  You were sending `res.json(200).send("...");`, I changed it to `res.status(200)...`